# How do you format XAML in Expression Blend?

Tags: .net, xaml, expression-blend

Does anyone know how to "format xaml" in Expression Blend similar to the option "Format Document" in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe there is an autoformat feature in Expression Blend.

You'd have to open it up in Visual Studio and format it there. You can also use a Visual Studio plugin called [XAML Scrubber](http://blog.nerdplusart.com/archives/xaml-scrubber-for-vs) to auto scrub the markup, but then you'd still have to paste it back into Blend.

Comment: Thanks.....I'm a bit baffled as to why they wouldn't have that basic functionality.

Comment: Boooo! Use this so often in VS

Comment: Plus one for being correct.  Boo MS for missing this feature. CNTL K (then D) !!! Please MS....

Answer (score 2):

Even in Blend 4 I couldn't find a way of doing this.
You can also download [Kaxaml](http://www.kaxaml.com/) which has an integrated XAML Scrubber.

Comment: Plus one for Kaxaml.  It puts the namespace items on separate lines.